# iterate over settings dictionary with Qsettings with boolean values

Tags: pyqt4, case-sensitive, qsettings

Hm, I thought I was clever to manage my PyQt settings with a (Python) dictionary. That way I thought I could iterate over the settings at least for saving and comparing.

But I got problems when using boolean values.

I have a method

```
def changed(self):
    s = QSettings()
    for key in self._options:
        #print key, self._options[key], s.value(key)
        if self._options[key] != s.value(key):
            return True
    return False
```

This works as long as there aren't any boolean values in s.
If there is a boolean value in the dictionary the function always returns True.

Uncommenting the `print` line shows the issue and results in

```
hasDefault True true
```

So the question is: what is this lowercase `true` that QSettings returns, and how can I get Python to compare this correctly to a boolean?

I read you should use `toBool()` to make up for different representations on different platforms. But I don't see how I can do this in such a loop (i.e. not knowing in advance what type there is to compare).

Any hint or solution appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the post was premature, but it was useful for getting things clear.

Further research showed that this is an issue with not-the-latest Qt versions, but that now QSettings.value() offers an optional `type` argument to specify the return type.

With

```
for key in self._options:
        if self._options[key] != s.value(key, type=type(self._options[key])):
            return True
    return False
```

I managed to set the type of `s.value()`s return to the type of the actual value in the dictionary.

May it help someone else ...